# Select using timestamp as a criteria

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a simple question.

I have a

column A> which is sales$

Column B> no of items sold

COLUMN T> Current timestamp

I have few sales which has `timestamp 0000-00-00 00:00:00`

This is my query

```
Select SUM(A) SALES,
       SUM(B) NO_OF_SALES
FROM simple_1
```

This query shows the entire sales $

This is the query I am trying

```
Select SUM(A) SALES,
           SUM(B) NO_OF_SALES
    FROM simple_1
WHERE T=0000-00-00 00:00:00
```

I get an error message saying the syntax is wrong,

Comment: Have you tried using quotes around the date: `WHERE T='0000-00-00 00:00:00'`?

Comment: What is the error text?

Comment: #1054-Unknow cloumn 'T' in 'where clause'

Comment: Is the column called T?

Comment: 0 row(s) affected.
Warning: #1265 Data truncated for column 'T' at row 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

should be

> T = 'yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss.000'

if it doesnt work can you please attached your schema. cheers.

Answer (score 0):

Put the timestamp in quotes

```
SELECT SUM(A) SALES,
       SUM(B) NO_OF_SALES
FROM simple_1
WHERE T = '0000-00-00 00:00:00'
```